# gwt date selection for birthdays that's not a calendar

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I'd like to find a slick date selection widget that's not a calendar widget... the three drop down approach is ugly.. the calendar widget is a pain in the butt for anyone who is not < 10 and free form text entry is painful on mobile devices. Does anyone know of an existing widget out there that makes birthdate selection relatively painless for GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there exists alternative datepickers for GWT. In GWT libraries such as GXT, Vaadin all date pickers are calendar pickers. 
But you can always implement non standard widget by yourself.

Here is non standard datepicker, from which you can get inspiration:
http://bugsvoice.com/applications/bugsVoice/site/test/calendarPickerDemo.jsp

Comment: I like that one! thanks.. I'll mark this as the answer since I'm pretty sure there is nothing off the shelf that suits my needs.